# MinGW: libgmp-10.dll is REALLY missing

Tags: c++, windows, dll

I'm trying to use NetBeans to compile c++ code.
Following the tutorials on the site i installed MinGW but it did not compile.
I discovered that cc1plus.exe (i guess it is launched by g++.exe) cannot find libgmp-10.dll.
Googling about it points to a lot of answers that tells to add the MinGW folder to the Windows path variables (which i've already done).
The fact is that i have not that DLL on my disk.
So, before going hunting for it on the web, since i'm pretty new to these stuffs (i'm a C++Builder user) i'd like to ask if i did something wrong with the MinGW installer or what should i do to make MinGW works.

Thanks

Comment: Your answer is within here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6951938/libgmp-10-dll-is-missing?rq=1

Comment: mh.... i missed that last, 0 votes comment which actually is what i need to do....
In details, i needed to go in the "base" folder and then download all the -dll files from the latest versions of mpc, mfpr and gmp (and find a program that handles the .lzma file type.

Comment: Ok, i don't know if i need to open another question or not... some admin or veteran user can suggest me what to do? I've found that i needed install the DLL packages from the MinGW installer... so technicallu this question is solved. But i still have problems in compiling (i'm missing a errno.h file, and i don't know where to get it...)

Comment: Could you answer the question with details (i.e. provide links, etc...)? (It's ok to answer your own question and accept it) I am struggling with this same issue. Thanks

Comment: I had to dig in the installer advanced option, reading almost all of them until i've checked some things related to DLLs that were necessary. I can't remember now which was... when i'll reainstall everything on the new PC i'll got in a months or so i'll answer here with the whole procedure. Sorry for not being more useful, but for now, just doublecheck the options of the installer.