# Cannot Compile C code with MinGW

Tags: c, windows, mingw

I am currently trying to compile and run C code on a Windows 8 machine and have installed MinGW so that I could do so. However, whenever I run the command to compile, I am told that the I: drive is missing and when I cancel the program tell me that libgmp-10.dll is missing. Here is the exact command I am using to try and compile:

```
"C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe" helloworld.c -o helloworld.exe
```

This leads to those two dialog boxes.

[image: The first dialog box to pop up.]

The first just says to insert the missing drive I. If I click Try Again, nothing happens and if I click the other two options, a second dialog box appears.

[image]

The second says that I am missing the libgmp-10.dll. I know for a fact that the dll exists in the same folder in which gcc.exe resides, and that the place where I am running these files from is off of the C drive drive. I have added "C:\MinGW\bin" to the path variable like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6951938/libgmp-10-dll-is-missing) question's answer suggests, but no dice.

TL:DR - Can use gcc from MinGW to compile C code. Adding bin to path did not solve 'missing dll problem' and dll exists in same folder as gcc.exe

Comment: Yes, you can use GCC with MinGW if it is correctly installed.  It seems from the errors you are getting that it is not correctly installed.  I would recommend reinstalling GCC in its entirety, preferably removing what's already there (but doing that may well be too hard to be worthwhile since most of it will simply be overwritten during the reinstall).

Comment: See [this](http://sourceforge.net/p/mingw/bugs/2108/) bug report if reinstalling doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling MingGW. It worked to me when i was getting trouble in Windows 8.