# G++ on Windows does not produce .exe file

Tags: c++, c, windows, gcc, g++

I have this project that I've been doing. On WSL, when I compile, there seem to be no issues. Everything works well and good.

However, I need the compiled code in a .exe format so I can run it on windows and call it within a Python code.

- I have installed flex, bison and MinGW (from mysys2) and all of them have been added to my path/environment variables.
- I have ran command prompt as Admin as well to avoid any permissions issues that may have come up.

[image: In this image]
In this image, flex command works without hitches and produces the lex.yy.c file as expected. **However, g++/gcc command does not show any error. Neither does it produce the .exe file**

[image: Over here]
Over here, I have compiled with -ll appended to the statement, and once again the same result.
**Note:** It took significantly longer to compiler with -ll appended than without. Not sure if this is significant information.

I found a thread([g++ does not make any file or give any output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45392444/g-does-not-make-any-file-or-give-any-output)) where someone addressed the same problem but there was no proper solution that has worked.

Does anyone know a solution or what the problem could be? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What if you compile with `-Wall -Werror`?

Comment: Msys2 has its own shell and you should probably run it instead of cmd.exe. The reason is that it will set different paths to dll's that its g++ needs. What maybe happened is, that g++ could not even be loaded because a static link to a dll could not be resolved by the loader.

Comment: @Cheatah No change in output when compiling with `-Wall -Werror`

Comment: @BerndElkemann I tried compiler under Msys2 now and it prompted regarding undefined yywrap(). I then defined it, but the end result is the same as the original problem. No output file

Comment: Did you check your AV? They like to eat freshly produced exe files.

Comment: @ReuelSam Please open the Msys2-Shell, and give us the infos you get from these 3 commands: "g++ --version" "which g++" and "where g++"

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]". Please don't post screenshots if they contain just text, copy-and-paste the text as such. Yes, even the Windows shells can do this. And if you cannot avoid screenshots, please make them visible. (I have done that for you.)