# The C preprocessor (MinGW's cpp.exe) produces no output

Tags: mingw, c-preprocessor

I am trying to run `C:\MinGW\bin\cpp.exe -v -o main.txt test.c` on test.c:

```
#ifdef HELLO
HELLO!
#else
BYE!
#endif
```

but only get the following output, no apparent error, and no `main.txt` is written (nor any other file):

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=C:\MinGW\bin\cpp.exe
Target: mingw32
Configured with: ../src/gcc-8.2.0/configure --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=mingw32 --target=mingw32 --prefix=/mingw --disable-win32-registry --with-arch=i586 --with-tune=generic --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,ada --with-pkgversion='MinGW.org GCC-8.2.0-5' --with-gmp=/mingw --with-mpfr=/mingw --with-mpc=/mingw --enable-static --enable-shared --enable-threads --with-dwarf2 --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-libiconv-prefix=/mingw --with-libintl-prefix=/mingw --enable-libstdcxx-debug --with-isl=/mingw --enable-libgomp --disable-libvtv --enable-nls --disable-build-format-warnings
Thread model: win32
gcc version 8.2.0 (MinGW.org GCC-8.2.0-5)
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-E' '-v' '-o' 'main.txt' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i586'
 c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/cc1.exe -E -quiet -v -iprefix c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/ test.c -o main.txt -mtune=generic -march=i586
```

---

I've found Denis Auroux / Tristan Miller's [GPP](https://logological.org/gpp) and a [windows build](https://github.com/makc/gpp.2.24-windows/releases) which works as expected (`gpp.exe -o main.txt test.c` - *actually, you'll want the `-C` option, see the [docs](https://files.nothingisreal.com/software/gpp/gpp.html)*), but I'm still interested in what the problem is with my usage of cpp.

Comment: Looks kind of like cc1 dies or doesn't even start. My cpp works fine. I suggest checking if Process Monitor can tell you more.

Comment: @DavidMacek Thanks! It died because it could not find a DLL because it was not set in *Path*... I did not get the error message dialog about this because the cmd.exe I was using was started in another application.

Comment: Happy to have helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was running this in a Command prompt "spawned" by a file manager.
Running `cmd.exe` directly, the following error message dialog is shown:

```
---------------------------
cc1.exe - System Error
---------------------------
The code execution cannot proceed because libgmp-10.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem. 
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

[Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) shows a final `Exit Status: 1` but I don't see above DLL when filtering for Process Name `cpp.exe`, though there are some `BUFFER OVERFLOW` results for `cc1.exe` as well.

The DLL in question is present in my `C:\MinGW\bin`, so adding this path to the *Environment Variables* not only fixes the issue "[libgmp-10.dll is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6951938/libgmp-10-dll-is-missing)", but also makes `cpp.exe` known so no path is needed when running it.

Comment: Buffer overflows in Process Monitor are usually harmless.